# Android location using Cell Tower

Tags: android

How can I retrieve my location using cell towers? when GPS and Wifi is off.

I know i can retrevive cellID of towers, but how can i map it to get Latitude and Longitude of my current location?

I don't care if it isn't accurate location.

I have found some snippets but seems using wifi.

Comment: you can find only CellId and Location Area Code(LAC) from cell tower. by using that values you can find lattitude and longitude with the help of internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

  int cellid= cellLocation.getCid();
  int celllac = cellLocation.getLac();

 Log.d("CellLocation", cellLocation.toString());
 Log.d("GSM CELL ID",  String.valueOf(cellid));
 Log.d("GSM Location Code", String.valueOf(celllac));
```

Make sure that you have those permissions in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

If you really want the real position use a httpclient or somewhat to query http://www.google.com/glm/mmap with your cellid and lac.  Example is listed here. [http://www.anddev.org/poor_mans_gps_-*celltowerid*-_location_area_code_-lookup-t257.html](http://www.anddev.org/poor_mans_gps_-_celltowerid_-_location_area_code_-lookup-t257.html)

Comment: @Mohammad Ali, thank you for updating the variable names. DIdnt see that they were wrong.

Comment: `getCellLocation() is deprecated as of API 26: Android 8.0 (Oreo)`