# Why, onlocationchanged no it's called when using data mobile?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, provider

when i use gps or wifi onlocationchanged works ok, but when i use data mobile, onlocationchanged it's called only one time and the  location provides it's bad.

i hope can you help me, i really need get location with data mobile.

this it's my code:

```
public class ObtenerLatLng implements LocationListener {

    public static double latitude = 0.0;
    public static double longitude = 0.0;
    public static boolean flaglocation=true;
    int contador;
    Context context;
    LocationManager locationManager;


    public ObtenerLatLng(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        obtenerlatlng(context);
    }

    public void obtenerlatlng(Context context) {


        Log.i("hola ", "Se HA SOLICITADO LOCALIZACION");
        NetworkInfo aux;
        NetworkInfo isWifiOn = null;
        NetworkInfo isMobiledataOn = null;



        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Network[] todas = cm.getAllNetworks();

            for (Network item : todas) {
                aux = cm.getNetworkInfo(item);
                if (aux.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    isWifiOn = aux;
                }
                if (aux.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    isMobiledataOn = aux;
                }
            }

        } else {
            isWifiOn = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            isMobiledataOn = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        }


        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {

            if (isMobiledataOn.isConnected() || isWifiOn.isConnected() ) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "entre a Network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 1, this);


                    }
                } else {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 1, this);

                }
            } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "entre a gps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 1, this);

                    }
                } else {

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 1, this);

                }

            }

        } else {
            flaglocation=false;
           // Toast.makeText(context, "Revise la configuracion de red", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location!= null ) {
            flaglocation=true;
            Toast.makeText(context, "Se actualizo la localizacion " + location.getLatitude() + "  " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();

        }

    }



    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mobile data you get only cell location. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23710085/3209739) on how to receive cell location.

Network_provider needs at least WiFi to receive network or coarse locations.

Comment: ok, but i have an question ,It is more accurate than gps or not ?

Comment: ok understand,i believed that gps it's more accurate, thank you very much

Comment: i'm sorry, i cannot vote up because i'm new in forum and i don't have enough reputation to do it. but i appreciate your answer, when I can do it I'll do.

Comment: I got it, thanks for that. You can accept answer by clicking on tick under down arrow..