# Getting Location In Android Without Location Service

Tags: android, gps, location

Is it possible to get location in android without enabling location service of android device ? I need to get location from nearest mobile tower, so is it possible ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710045/android-location-using-cell-tower

Comment: you can get location based on IP for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `getLastKnownLocation()` of `FusedLocationAPI`. This doesnot involve enabling location services.
As per docs:

> Using the Google Play services location APIs, your app can request the
>   last known location of the user's device. In most cases, you are
>   interested in the user's current location, which is usually equivalent
>   to the last known location of the device

.